# Java MySQL Programming

Tags: java, mysql

I am accessing a MySQL table that has over 1 million or more Records. I am using My SQL query browser which is unable to grab all the records and it break the connection in the middle. 
Now I have to write a Java Program which access that particular table without being broken in the middle as this table will be modified and accessed frequently.

Can you experts suggest me how should do I go over this problem

either I create an Index on the table and how do I create index

Comment: I don't get the point: Do you really want to call over 1 million rows to be displayed to you? Who should read all these rows? Perhaps it would be a good idea to learn about SQL and what it is and what it is used for.

Answer (score 1):

There are [different reasons why a MySQL connection might break](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) during a query. Can you give the exact error message you receive?

#### A simplified explanation on how to add an index to the table for a simple query

1. Look at the field(s) in the WHERE
   clause of the query
2. Add an index on the field(s) using
   ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX
3. Use EXPLAIN on the query and check
   if the query is actually using the
   index.

IF you want more specific help, Post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the  `EXPLAIN` of your query.

Comment: I am getting following exact error while executing the query in MySQL query browser". The memory load of the system is extremely high.This is likely because of current result being very large. In order to keep system responsive record set retrieval has been stopped". Is there a way I can find the last entry or number of entries in the table. And can I request data from the table in chunks or define a range.

Comment: Your database (server) is working fine, it's the clientside that cannot handle the load. You should request the table in chunks, defining a range, using the LIMIT statement: `select ID from table LIMIT 0,50`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL query browser limits the number of records to be displayed for performance reasons, because it is an interactive program and nobody like to wait for half an hour before the program crashes with an out-of-memory error. You can change these limits in the settings.

Your Java program will face similar problems.

When using large datasets it is important to plan how you are going to access that dataset and create the necessary indexes.

It would be useful to edit the question to show the structure of the data. Generqlly it looks like this :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer_name ON customer (name);
```

[Here are more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

If you just want to dump the data to work on the data using Excel you can try this on the commandline

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -t -T/path/to/directory [database] --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

In my experience this is a very painful exercise as Excel really is not made to deal with this amount of rows, and the dump format usually is slightly, but infuriatingly incompatible.

Your best bet is to invest an hour of your time to go through a SQL tutorial like [sql fundamentals](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/sqlfundamentals.htm) and play with MySQL query browser to get a feel of what you can do with SQL. I guarantee your investment paid itself back by tomorrow.

Comment: I am getting following error while executing the query in  MySQL query browser " The memory load of the system is extremely high. This is likely because of current result being very large . In order to keep system responsive record set retrieval has been stopped". Is there a way I can find the last entry  or number of entries in the table. And can I request data from the table in chunks

Comment: @user448059: You can find number of entries by using SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE. Then you can use SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 5000; to get next 1000 entries starting at position 5000.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very well used to MySQL programming, but generally indexes are used to arrange the values of one or more columns in a database table in specific order.

SYNTAX

CREATE INDEX IndexName ON tableName (column);

Just go through this tutorial for more information,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html